# Bash Script Exits su or ssh Session Rather than Script

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I am using CentOS 5.4.  I created a bash script that does some checking before running any commands.  If the check fails, it will simply `exit 0`.  The problem I am having is that on our server, the script will exit the `su` or `ssh` session when the `exit 0` is called.

```
#!/bin/bash
# check if directory has contents and exit if none
if [ -z "`ls /ebs_raid/import/*.txt 2>/dev/null`" ]; then
  echo "ok"
  exit 0
fi
```

here is the output:

```
[root@ip-10-251-86-31 ebs_raid]# . test.sh 
ok
[russ@ip-10-251-86-31 ebs_raid]$
```

as you can see, I was removed from my sudo session, if I wasn't in the sudo session, it would have logged me out of my ssh session.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here or where to start.

Comment: You can do this, by the way: `if ! ls /ebs_raid/import/*.txt 2>/dev/null; then`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `.` to run a shell script it executes in the current shell rather than starting a new shell.  Type `bash test.sh` to get the behaviour you want.